# What does this traffic sign mean?

Tags: super-hxeros

At about 1:59 in the 12th episode of *SUPER HXEROS*, there is a traffic sign of a red circle with a red slash inside.

on the left top of the picture:
[image: picture]

What does this traffic sign mean? Does it mean car parking is forbidden? Do the characters break the rule?

Comment: stop sign? or still no?

Comment: FYI Parking forbidden sign is [314 here](https://www.zurich.co.jp/car/useful/guide/cc-roadsign-list-meaning/?utm_medium=pas&utm_source=iya&utm_campaign=tx&utm_content=100046&argument=hT7qcPFB&dmai=pas_iya_tx_100046&yclid=YSS.1001033242.EAIaIQobChMIgM6c7arj-gIV1cEWBR3Ggg7CEAAYAiAAEgKqmPD_BwE). And strictly speaking, the sign in the pic is nonexistent - the line must be from top-left to bottom-right.

Answer (score 6):

The [sign](https://japan-cycling.com/road-signs/) means

> Closed to motor vehicles

Since they are standing in front of it, they are not breaking the rules.